# function Map.put/4 is undefined or private

Tags: web, elixir, backend, phoenix-framework

I just started to learn elixir and phoenix.

I am trying to add comments to blog but i got this error

```
function Map.put/4 is undefined or private
```

Error is in this line (show.html.heex):

```
<%= render "comment_form.html", Map.put(assigns, :changeset, :action, Routes.post_post_path(@conn, :add_comment, @post)) %>
```

My code in post_controller.ex

```
  def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
      post =
          id
            |> Posts.get_post!
            |> Repo.preload([:comments])

      changeset = Comment.changeset(%Comment{}, %{})
      render(conn, "show.html", post: post, changeset: changeset)
  end
```

And comment_form.html.heex

```
<%= form_for @changeset, @action, fn f -> %>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <%= text_input f, :name, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Content</label>
        <%= textarea f, :content, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= submit "Add comment", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have accidently added `:changeset` in the code:

```
- Map.put(assigns, :changeset, :action, Routes.post_post_path(@conn, :add_comment, @post))
+ Map.put(assigns, :action, Routes.post_post_path(@conn, :add_comment, @post))
```

[`Map.put/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#put/3) can put a new key-value pair into an existing map. Here `3` means the arity (the number of arguments) is 3.

In your case, it makes little sense to put a new assign of `:changeset` into the inherited assigns which already contain that key.